# Android Notification trigger when the application is in the background

Tags: android

All, in my new android application i need a notification to trigger if the app is not used for last four days. That is from the last use of application if 4 days gone and not using the application a notification need to come.

plz any help will be apreciated...

thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to manage it by yourself.

1.) Set a preference to the time you want the alarm to go off, it will save, even after reboot.

2.) you need RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED permission and register a BroadcastReceiver in your manifest for the BOOT_COMPLETED

3.) just reset the alarm time to the time you need, from the preference.

Comment: pretty busy atm, and i've never done that (because i don't want to annoy my users), so i can't type it out of my head. maybe anyone else has time to guide him?

Comment: This works only if the app is installed in the phone memory. If we install in the sd card we never get the BOOT_COMPLETED broad cast

Answer (score 0):

I think that's very bad practise... but if you want to do it nevertheless, simply use AlarmManager.

Comment: bu if we switch off and later switch on is the alarm goes?